# I accidentally deleted the XIB file - how do I fix this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I made a mistake and deleted the XIB by accident. The application still works, but I can't see or edit the XIB file. How do I recreate or find the XIB?

Comment: You need to post the practical portion along with your question to get the desired answer.

Comment: You need to post the code snippet you already tried.

Comment: I don't need any code
I write some application and I delete the XIB class the class with al the buttons
and I want to return this class I remove it (mistake) but the app is still work good with all the buttons
so what that I don't understand is how the class not showing but the app still working

Comment: user1034172: It's possible that you removed the reference to the XIB from Xcode but the file's still there on disk -- check in your project directory to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Use source code version control (SVN or GIT) next time, and put the xibs under version control.  Periodic backups (such as Time Machine) might also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like the compiled xib (= the nib file) is still around in your build folder, if you clean your project that'll be gone too.

Unless you have a backup (always make backups!) there's not much you can do at this point. You could try and search for the nib, then try to decompile it (I've never done that, I don't know how good the result would be), but that's probably going to be more work than just starting from scratch.